# Is it possible to write to multiple binary files in a loop

Tags: c++, io, binary, ofstream

I am trying to open a binary file, read from it and then open multiple files with `std::ofstream`and write into seperate files randomly. However, i get some garbage values in the written binary file. Is it not possible to write into multiple files paralel? What could be the cause of this issue?

Because when i create one ofstream and write everything, it seems okay. Here is my code for writing to binary:

```
//For reading from a binary file
std::ifstream fileInput;
fileInput.exceptions(std::ifstream::failbit | std::ifstream::badbit);

const int numberOfFiles = 5;
std::ofstream outfile[numberOfFiles];

std::stringstream sstm;
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfFiles; i++)
{
    sstm.str("");
    sstm << "test" << i;
    outfile[i].open(sstm.str());
}

try
{
    fileInput.open("TestBinary.dat", std::ios::binary);
    float f;
    int newLineCounter = 0;
    int index = 0;

    while (fileInput.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&f), sizeof(float)))
    {
        outfile[index].write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&f), sizeof(float));
        newLineCounter++;

        // Since i am reading 3D points
        if (newLineCounter == 3)
        {
            index = rand() % numberOfFiles;
            newLineCounter = 0;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfFiles; i++)
    {
        outfile[i].close();
    }
    fileInput.close();
}
catch (std::ifstream::failure e) {
    std::cerr << "Exception opening/reading/closing file\n";
}
```

when i read the file i get garbage values like this:
`979383418452721018666090051403776.000000 500207915157676809436722056201764864.000000 2.16899e+17`

Comment: ***Is it possible to write to multiple binary files in a loop*** Yes of course.

Comment: Alright :) but is creating array of ofstreams the right way to do it?

Comment: It's one way to do this that should work. I have not figured out your bug yet.

Comment: Can you tell me what are the other ways to do this?

Comment: Use a vector instead or open a file each time in the loop. With that said I don't think your code that is presented in the question is your problem. I think its either your input file or how you are reading the created data files. Maybe you want to debug and look a the value of `f` that is read in the loop. If you don't have a good debugger like `gdb` or `Visual Studio` simply printing the value could help.

Comment: May not be the problem, but you're opening your files in text mode.  You should use `outfile[i].open(sstm.str(), ios_base::out | ios_base::binary)` to use binary mode.

Comment: Perhaps that reinterpret cast is doing bad things?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm Exactly the problem was because of this thank you for the comment. I would like to accept is as an answer if you would like to convert your comment to an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're opening your files in text mode.  You need to open them in binary mode.

```
outfile[i].open(sstm.str(), ios_base::out | ios_base::binary);
```